# Panda3d globalClock.getDt() function does not work, do I need to import something?

Tags: python, pycharm, panda3d

I've been watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Li5fc9u35M&ab_channel=AtiByte) on how to use Panda3d. I cannot get globalClock to not have red squigglies in Pycharm. I'd love some help; do I need to import something? Here is my code:

```
from panda3d.core import loadPrcFileData


confVars = """
win-size 1280 720
window-title My Game
cursor-hidden false
show-frame-rate-meter 1
show-scene-graph-analyzer-meter 1
undecorated
"""
loadPrcFileData("", confVars)

class myGame(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)

        self.jack = self.loader.loadModel("models/jack")
        self.jack.reparentTo(self.render)
        self.x = 0
        self.speed = 2
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self, task):
        dt = globalClock.getDt()
        self.angle = 0
        self.x = self.speed = dt
        return task.cont
```

Comment: The code isn't runnable. Please include the rest or create a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

```
import direct.showbase.ShowBaseGlobal

dt = direct.showbase.ShowBaseGlobal.globalClock.getDt()
```

OR

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBaseGlobal import globalClock

dt = globalClock.getDt()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The first option worked for me, my linter fails on the second.